# Android AndEngine creating a body behind the sprite exactly

Tags: android, sprites, andengine

I am using AndEngine for Android. I created a body, but it is not behind the sprite as I wanted.

```
                                Body.setTransform(Sprite.getX()/32, Sprite.getY()/32, 0);
```

This is what I am currently using and this is how it appears.

[image]

My body is the white circular borders, and my sprite is the red circle.

**and** When I remove `/32` from the code the body doesn't even appear.

Extra code;

```
                    FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(
                            1,     // density
                            0.75f,  // elasticity
                            0.5f, // friction
                            false); // isSensor
```

the Body

```
                Body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.physicsWorld, Sprite, BodyType.KinematicBody, this.FIXTURE_DEF);
                Body.setUserData("eSprite");
                this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(Sprite, Body, true, true)
```

my sprite is 65px ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an 'andengine' user so I can't give you the correct code.

However it seems that your problem is that you are targeting the sprite x & y position which is wrong.

You must target the sprite x + **his center x**, and the sprite y + **his center y**.

```
Body.setTransform((Sprite.getX() + Sprite.getWidth()/2) /32, (Sprite.getY()+Sprite.getHeight()/2)/32, 0);
```

I guess 32 is the indice to convert values for your box2d world. if you don't know the correct way to do it you should use this code :

```
 indice_w = box2d_width / render_width;
 indice_h = box2d_height / render_height;
```

**render_width** is camera viewport used to render the sprite;

**box2d_width** is the viewport of your box2d world;

Thus you can do this code :

```
Body.setTransform((Sprite.getX() + Sprite.getWidth()/2) * indice_w, (Sprite.getY()+Sprite.getHeight()/2) * indice_h, 0);
```

I hope this will help you.